# Find-file with a hint?

Tags: emacs, elisp

Is there a way to give the 'find-file' function a hint?

I'm working with files in the same directory on a remote server, and I'm getting tired of typing in the machine name, and directory structure all the time.  It would sure be great if I could write a function that would bring up the find-file prompt with the machine name and directory already filled in.

(Note: I use Emacs 23.1)

Thanks for your help in advance.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you're starting the `'find-file` command from buffers associated with files on the remote server, the staring point should already include the directory/remote server filled in.

One way to skin this cat is to do

```
M-x cd /ssh:user@machine:/starting/path
```

*note:* I use tramp, and that's how find-file starts.  I'd not noticed the `/ssh:` before today, but I don't use tramp very much any longer.

To answer your question directly, this command calls find-file with the "hint":

```
(defun my-remote-find-file ()
  "call 'find-file with a starting directory"
  (interactive)
  (let ((default-directory "/ssh:user@machine:/starting/path/"))
    (call-interactively 'find-file)))
```

Obviously customize the starting point.

One last way I can think of solving this is to do `M-x dired` on the remote server, and do your file finding from that point.

Comment: Thanks for your help.  You've taught me a little bit more about emacs and lisp.

Answer (score 0):

Set up [recentf](http://www.emacswiki.org/emacs/RecentFiles), and when you want to open a file on the server, go through the recentf menu; if the exact file you want is not there, just open something else in the same directory, then type `C-x C-f` and the directory should be filled in for you.

Comment: I like this approach.  It's not exactly what I'm looking for, but I'll give it a try.

Answer (score 0):

Use a *bookmark* to get to the remote directory. Then, as noted by Trey above, once you're in a file or directory that is remote, the `default-directory` will be set to what you want.

You can bookmark a remote file or directory.  With [***Bookmark+***](http://www.emacswiki.org/emacs/BookmarkPlus), when you bookmark a Dired buffer you can save also all its file markings, omissions etc. -- IOW, the Dired state.  When you later jump to the bookmark that saved state is restored.  Use bookmarks to organize code projects etc.

[bookmarks](/questions/tagged/bookmarks)[bookmark](/questions/tagged/bookmark)